# Save line geometry as points geometry using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, point, geometry

I have line and polygon layers. I want to make a list of points' coordinates (ends or begginings of lines), which are touching the polygons. The coordinates which I need are selected as yellow.

[image]

With the code I have right now I get coordinates of the whole line. How to change it? Here is the part of the code and visualisation of my result:

[image]

```py
lineFeatures = lines.getFeatures()

lakes = []

for lineFeat in lineFeatures:
    lineGeom = lineFeat.geometry()
    polygonFeatures = polygons.getFeatures()

    for polygonFeat in polygonFeatures:
        polyGeom = polygonFeat.geometry()

        if lineGeom.touches(polyGeom): 
            lakes.append(lineGeom.asPolyline()[0])
            lakes.append(lineGeom.asPolyline()[1])
```

The points in the pictures are there just for visualization. In my project, I have only lines and polygons.

I am working with QGIS and Python.

Comment: Your code works for me. Perhaps two aspects: 1) The line 'for polygonFeat in ...' must be indented. 2) Are the geometries actually above each other or a little off?

Comment: 1) Yes, it is indented in the original version, i just made a mistake with copying. I changed it already in my question. 2) The lines are snapped to polygons, so they are actually above each other. I know also that this code works, but it just not I wanted to obtain and I do not have how to change it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out with 'intersects' and 'intersection' methods. Next code produces only two points.

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

feats_line = [ feat for feat in layers[0].getFeatures() ]

feats_poly = [ feat for feat in layers[1].getFeatures() ]

for feat_l in feats_line:
    for feat_p in feats_poly:
        if feat_p.geometry().intersects(feat_l.geometry()):
            geom = feat_p.geometry().intersection(feat_l.geometry())
            print geom.asPolyline()[0]
            print geom.asPolyline()[1]
```

I tested it with next simple hypothetical situation:

[image]

and it works. Points printed at the Python Console were:

```
(386524,4.45324e+06)
(410342,4.44987e+06)
```

**Editing Note:**

With 4 lines:

[image]

running this code:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

feats_line = [ feat for feat in layers[0].getFeatures() ]

feats_poly = [ feat for feat in layers[1].getFeatures() ]

my_list_points = []

for feat_l in feats_line:
    for feat_p in feats_poly:
        if feat_p.geometry().intersects(feat_l.geometry()):
            geom = feat_p.geometry().intersection(feat_l.geometry())
            my_list_points.append(geom.asPolyline()[0])
            my_list_points.append(geom.asPolyline()[1])

print my_list_points
```

produces a list with 8 points:

```
[(387941,4.45518e+06), (410116,4.45158e+06), (385087,4.45128e+06), (411027,4.44466e+06), (383102,4.44575e+06), (408687,4.43823e+06), (392714,4.4348e+06), (405952,4.43338e+06)]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, now it is working! I just have one question: why in my case (4 lines intersecting polygon), the code creates 4 geoms, but only one of them contains points?

Comment: Perhaps, the append to the list is not well codified. I slightly modified my code to include it and it works well (see my editing note).

Comment: I still get the error: my_list_points.append(geom.asPolyline()[0])
IndexError: list index out of range. I solved it as in the edit up in my question, but I just wanted to know how this function works that it is giving me empty lists...

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the segments of the line to find the one that touches/intersect the polygons (as in [Get the vertices on a LineString either side of a Point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84522))

[image]

I show here the results with one line and one polygon as example

```
# transform the line to a list of points
linegeom = liengeom.asPolyline() 
# extract the segments seg_start, seg_end of the line
for seg_start, seg_end in zip(lineGeom, lineGeom[1:]):
   line_start = QgsPoint(seg_start)
   line_end = QgsPoint(seg_end) 
   segment = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start,line_end])
   if segment.touches(polyGeom): # or if segment.intersects(polyGeom): 
       # segment is the result with line_start and line_end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@sweet.sugar.cola answered to her own question

> From one of the answers, I found a solution. The code below do exactly
> what I wanted.
>
> ```py
> lakes=[]
>
> lineFeatures = [feat for feat in lines.getFeatures()]
> polyFeatures = [feat for feat in polygons.getFeatures()]
>
> for lineFeat in lineFeatures:
>     for polyFeat in polyFeatures:
>         if polyFeat.geometry().intersects(lineFeat.geometry()):
>             geom = polyFeat.geometry().intersection(lineFeat.geometry())
>             line_intersection = geom.asPolyline()
>             if line_intersection:
>                 lakes.append(line_intersection[0])
>                 lakes.append(line_intersection[1])
> ```