# Creating line pattern fill using geometry generator (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geometry-generator

I'm trying to make a line pattern fill in QGIS using the geometry generator and a Python function.

The code is inspired from this answer : [Save line geometry as points geometry in QGIS (pyqgis)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201289/save-line-geometry-as-points-geometry-in-qgis-pyqgis)

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def fill_line_pattern(x, feature, parent):

#create a base line that is 45 degrees
base_xmin = 2285865.0
base_xmax = 2669093.0
base_ymin = 1017594.0
base_ymax = 1399851.0

#calculating interval between parrallels
countX = int((2800000.0-2285865.0) / xInterval)
#empty list
pt=[]
pts = []
intersected_lines = []
#raw lines creation
for xOff in range(countX+1):
    ptXmin = base_xmin + xOff*(xInterval)
    ptXmax = base_xmax + xOff*(xInterval)
    ptmin = QgsPoint(ptXmin,base_ymin)
    ptmax = QgsPoint(ptXmax,base_ymax)
    pt = ([ptmin, ptmax])
    pts.append(pt)
#intersect lines with polygons
#for f in feat :
for p in pts :
    rawlines = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(p)
    if feature.geometry().intersects(rawlines):
        geom = feature.geometry().intersection(rawlines)
        intersected_lines.append(geom.asPolyline())
#create lines
for line_ok in intersected_lines:
    return QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(line_ok)
```

The issue is that the first line only is crossing the polygon...

[image]

How can I have all the lines crossing the polygons?

In comparison to the inspirational code above, there's no loop for the polygon features.

In the function, the feature called is a `QgsFeature` which can't use `getQgsFeatures()`.

If a for loop is used :

```
for f in feature :
    for p in pts :
    rawlines = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(p)
        if f.geometry().intersects(rawlines):
            geom = f.geometry().intersection(rawlines)
            intersected_lines.append(geom.asPolyline())
```

This error message appears:

> Evaluation error: 'int' object has no attribute 'geometry'

**EDIT**

The code below does almost what I want, it seems a little bit buggy because not all the intersections appear... The other disadvantage is the long time QGIS takes to render it on the canvas and in the composer.

On the other hand, the pdf output size is **so light** and is competitive with other software.

**Maps are made to be shared: QGIS biggest issue is PDF output file size**

The inspiration of the source : https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/06/05/qgis-function-editor/

Lutra Consulting uses a cache but I didn't find the way to do it...

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

def _layer_intersection(layer, xInterval):
#make 45 degrees lines from layer extent
    ext = layer.extent()
    xmax = ext.xMaximum()
    ymax = ext.yMaximum()
    xmin = ext.xMinimum()
    ymin = ext.yMinimum()

    pts_hash_box = []
    line_in_polygon = []

    x_base_min = xmin - (ymax-ymin)
    countX = int(((xmax-xmin)+(ymax-ymin)) / xInterval)

    for xOff in range(countX+1):
        ptXmin = x_base_min + xOff*(xInterval)
        ptXmax = xmin + xOff*(xInterval)

        ptmin_hash_box = QgsPointXY(ptXmin,ymin)
        ptmax_hash_box = QgsPointXY(ptXmax,ymax)

        pt_hash_box = ([ptmin_hash_box, ptmax_hash_box])
        pts_hash_box.append(pt_hash_box)

    multipolylines = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY(pts_hash_box)

    #intersection between 45 degrees virtual lines and the polygon features
    for layer_feature in layer.getFeatures() :
        if layer_feature.geometry().intersects(multipolylines):
            pts = layer_feature.geometry().intersection(multipolylines).asMultiPolyline()
            for pt in pts :
                line_in_polygon.append(y)

return QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY(line_in_polygon)

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def line_pattern_fill(layer_name, xInterval, feature, parent):
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.name() == layer_name :
        return _layer_intersection(layer, xInterval)
```

Comment: Must the lines be true geometry or could you use the [QgsLinePatternFillSymbolLayer()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLinePatternFillSymbolLayer.html) instead?

Comment: The lines doesn't have to be true geometry. 
QgsLinePatternFillSymbolLayer() is rasterized when exported in PDF. The consequence is that the PDF size increase considerably... 
So I was thinking about a new methodology to keep vectorized line pattern to preserve the size of my PDFs with QGIS.

Comment: @geavcon did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @geavcon: are you really sure that printing with line pattern is rasterized ? For me, it's exported to vectors (pdf).

Comment: @J.Monticolo I get the same rasterized result as geavcon reported. Which version of QGIS are you using? Are you exporting a PDF with a polygon that has a Line Pattern Fill?

Comment: @TeddyTedTed: I'm using QGIS 3.12 on Ubuntu. But I've just zoom at max on pdf and line pattern didn't seem to be rasterized. I just check the pdf and svg export with Inkscape and yes ... it's sad ... line pattern fill is rasterized.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT 2**

This bug is finally resolved (wait the version 3.24 (2022)) : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/45654

---

Here is my working solution. I took a great part of your code but rearranged and improved it.

Create a custom function in the function editor and paste the code below.

Use it as : `line_pattern_fill(@layer_id, 45, 1000)` where <kbd>45</kbd> is the angle in degrees and <kbd>1000</kbd> is the X interval in layer units.

I create, as Lutra Consulting blog post, a cache. I reinitialize the variable if the `angle` or `x_interval` change so that QGIS compute new pattern fills.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from math import ceil, cos, radians, sin

cache = {}


@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='geom_generator')
def line_pattern_fill(layer_id, angle, x_interval, feature, parent):
    """
    Returns a MultiLineString geometry with line pattern fill, contained
    in the current feature geometry.
    <h4>Syntax</h4>
    <div class="syntax">
    <code><span class="functionname">line_pattern_fill</span>
    (<span class="argument">@layer_id</span>,
    <span class="argument">angle</span>,
    <span class="argument">x interval</span>)</code>
    <h4>Arguments</h4>
    <div class="arguments">
    <table><tr>
    <td class="argument">@layer_id</td><td>ID of current layer</td></tr><tr>
    <td class="argument">angle</td><td>angle in degrees, from 0 to 179</td></tr><tr>
    <td class="argument">x interval</td><td>spacing between lines, in layer units</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <h4>Examples</h4>
    <div class="examples">
    <ul>
    <li><code>line_pattern_fill(@layer_id, 45, 1000)</code> &rarr; 
    <code>a line pattern fill at 45 degrees, spaced by 1000 layer units</code></li>
    <li><code>line_pattern_fill(@layer_id, 0, 60)</code> &rarr; 
    <code>a vertical line pattern fill, spaced by 60 layer units</code></li>
    <li><code>line_pattern_fill(@layer_id, 90, 150)</code> &rarr; 
    <code>a horizontal line pattern fill, spaced by 150 layer units</code></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    """
    global cache
    key1 = f"{angle}_{x_interval}"
    key2 = feature.id()
    if layer_id in cache:
        if not key1 in cache[layer_id]:
            cache[layer_id] = {key1: {}}
    else:
        cache[layer_id] = {key1: {}}

    if key2 not in cache[layer_id][key1]:
        pts_hash_box = []
        bbox = feature.geometry().boundingBox()
        xcoords = [bbox.xMinimum(), bbox.xMaximum()]
        ycoords = [bbox.yMinimum(), bbox.yMaximum()]

        xcoef = round(cos(radians(angle)), 5)
        ycoef = round(sin(radians(angle)), 5)
        fn = lambda x, y: ycoef * y - xcoef * x

        ccorners = [fn(x, y) for x in xcoords for y in ycoords]
        cmin = min(ccorners)
        cmax = max(ccorners)
        cvar = cmax - cmin

        for i in range(0, ceil(cvar), x_interval):
            c = cmin + i
            if xcoef == 0:
                xs = []
            else:
                xs = [((ycoef * y - c) / xcoef, y) for y in ycoords]

            if ycoef == 0:
                ys = []
            else:
                ys = [(x, (xcoef * x + c) / ycoef) for x in xcoords]

            pts = [
                (x, y)
                for x, y in xs + ys
                if xcoords[0] <= x <= xcoords[1] and ycoords[0] <= y <= ycoords[1]
            ]
            pt_hash_box = [QgsPointXY(x, y) for x, y in sorted(pts)]
            pts_hash_box.append(pt_hash_box)

        multipolylines = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY(pts_hash_box)
        geom = multipolylines.intersection(feature.geometry())
        if geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
            cache[layer_id][key1][key2] = geom
        elif geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.GeometryCollection:
            if geom.convertGeometryCollectionToSubclass(QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry):
                cache[layer_id][key1][key2] = geom
            else:
                cache[layer_id][key1][key2] = QgsGeometry()
        else:
            cache[layer_id][key1][key2] = QgsGeometry()

    return cache[layer_id][key1][key2]
```

---

**EDIT**

- Code improved : `QgsGeometry.intersection()` produce sometimes a `GeometryCollection` with lines and points. If the result of intersection is a collection, the code try to convert it to Line geometry type.
- Angle choice added : the angle argument is now in the code. The angle is in degrees. Rewritten code for this.
- Change `wkbType` to `type` : `LineGeometry` is more generic and works with `MultiLineStringZ` and all other Line types.
- Formatting help : adapt function help to QGIS expression function help format

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work for some features in layer. I apply to different layers, but the result is the same.

Comment: Is the geometry of the feature is valid ? Can you give a geometry as an example and test ?

Comment: [Sample data](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0bdce303f86ac8d2aa1f2b53a6d00d3f20200320125245/43af65a442641b25a9cd0134ca58ddf320200320125245/07781c)

Comment: When I try this the "Output previous" says "<geometry; Point>". And when I apply the styling (as a point geometry type) it just shows the first point on the first feature. EDIT: Nevermind! That was with a scratch layer, working fine with Spatialite so far

Comment: Is there a way to include a parameter for rotation? I have multiple layouts which are all at different orientations and the line pattern fill is 45 degrees from north but I would like it to be 45 degrees from the layout rotation. Thanks so much for this.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz: thanks for the data and code improved.

Comment: @TeddyTedTed: angle choice done. You can play with all angles as you want !

Comment: @J.Monticolo that's fantastic thank you so much. I can see there's a lot of work gone into that, much appreciated!